# Estimate of $x^s/s$ in contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $x>1$ and $S_R$ be a semi-circle enclosing the origin centered at $x=c \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ with radius $R>c$. Evaluate the integral $$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{S_R} \frac{x^s}{s}ds$$ as $R\to\infty$

The book I'm reading, Problems in Analytic Number Theory (M. Ram Murty) p.307, offers a solution by estimating the integral as follows:

$$\left |\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{S_R} \frac{x^s}{s}ds \right | \ll \frac{x^c}{2\pi}\int_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2}x^{R\cos{\varphi}}d\varphi$$

How was this estimate obtained? I'm guessing its just some standard substitution I'm missing.

Comment: I guess the upper bound of the integral should be $3\pi/2$ as in the estimate on the previous page (it doesn't really matter if we interpret $\varphi$ as an element of $\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$ with the right orientation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S_R$ is parameterized by $\phi(t)=Re^{it}+c$ for $t\in [\pi/2,3\pi/2]$. Hence we get: \begin{align*}
\int_{S_R}\frac{x^s}{s}ds = \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\frac{x^{Re^{it}+c}}{Re^{it}+c}Rie^{it}dt
\end{align*}
For large $R$ we have $|\frac{Rie^{it}}{Re^{it}+c}|\approx1$, thus this integral is in absolute value $$\ll x^c\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}|x^{Re^{it}}|dt$$
Now note $|x^{Re^{it}}|=x^{\operatorname{Re}(Re^{it})}=x^{R\cos t}$